# getting token information like name , symbol , decimals , supply , and liquidity pool

Tags: javascript, html, web3js

I am trying to get info from the router with javascript and web3js but I am stuck on pool liquidity information I have to upload my code part 2 is not configured because I need help on part 2

Token Name: Tether USD (Working)
Token Symbol : USDT (Working)
Token Decimals: 18 (Working)
Token Supply: 4979997922.172658408539526181 (Working)
Token Price BNB: 0.003138741447437976 (Working)
Token Price USD: 0.9950030495648159 (Working)

Part 2 needs Help in this

MarketCap : (Need help)
Total BNB in Pool : (Need help)
Total USDT in Pool : (Need help)

---

BNB Price: 317.007012596400825825

Thanks

```js
let pancakeSwapAbi=[{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"_factory",type:"address"},{internalType:"address",name:"_WETH",type:"address"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"constructor"},{inputs:[],name:"WETH",outputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"",type:"address"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"tokenA",type:"address"},{internalType:"address",name:"tokenB",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountADesired",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountBDesired",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountAMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountBMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"addLiquidity",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountA",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountB",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"liquidity",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"token",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountTokenDesired",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountTokenMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETHMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"addLiquidityETH",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountToken",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETH",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"liquidity",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"payable",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"factory",outputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"",type:"address"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOut",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"reserveIn",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"reserveOut",type:"uint256"}],name:"getAmountIn",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountIn",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"pure",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountIn",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"reserveIn",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"reserveOut",type:"uint256"}],name:"getAmountOut",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOut",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"pure",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOut",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"}],name:"getAmountsIn",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256[]",name:"amounts",type:"uint256[]"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountIn",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"}],name:"getAmountsOut",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256[]",name:"amounts",type:"uint256[]"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountA",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"reserveA",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"reserveB",type:"uint256"}],name:"quote",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountB",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"pure",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"tokenA",type:"address"},{internalType:"address",name:"tokenB",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"liquidity",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountAMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountBMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"removeLiquidity",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountA",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountB",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"token",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"liquidity",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountTokenMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETHMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"removeLiquidityETH",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountToken",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETH",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"token",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"liquidity",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountTokenMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETHMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"removeLiquidityETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETH",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"token",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"liquidity",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountTokenMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETHMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"bool",name:"approveMax",type:"bool"},{internalType:"uint8",name:"v",type:"uint8"},{internalType:"bytes32",name:"r",type:"bytes32"},{internalType:"bytes32",name:"s",type:"bytes32"}],name:"removeLiquidityETHWithPermit",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountToken",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETH",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"token",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"liquidity",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountTokenMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETHMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"bool",name:"approveMax",type:"bool"},{internalType:"uint8",name:"v",type:"uint8"},{internalType:"bytes32",name:"r",type:"bytes32"},{internalType:"bytes32",name:"s",type:"bytes32"}],name:"removeLiquidityETHWithPermitSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountETH",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"tokenA",type:"address"},{internalType:"address",name:"tokenB",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"liquidity",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountAMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountBMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"bool",name:"approveMax",type:"bool"},{internalType:"uint8",name:"v",type:"uint8"},{internalType:"bytes32",name:"r",type:"bytes32"},{internalType:"bytes32",name:"s",type:"bytes32"}],name:"removeLiquidityWithPermit",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountA",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountB",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOut",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapETHForExactTokens",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256[]",name:"amounts",type:"uint256[]"}],stateMutability:"payable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOutMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapExactETHForTokens",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256[]",name:"amounts",type:"uint256[]"}],stateMutability:"payable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOutMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",outputs:[],stateMutability:"payable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountIn",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOutMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapExactTokensForETH",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256[]",name:"amounts",type:"uint256[]"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountIn",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOutMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountIn",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOutMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapExactTokensForTokens",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256[]",name:"amounts",type:"uint256[]"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountIn",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOutMin",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOut",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountInMax",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapTokensForExactETH",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256[]",name:"amounts",type:"uint256[]"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountOut",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amountInMax",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address[]",name:"path",type:"address[]"},{internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"deadline",type:"uint256"}],name:"swapTokensForExactTokens",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256[]",name:"amounts",type:"uint256[]"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{stateMutability:"payable",type:"receive"}];
let tokenAbi=[{inputs:[{internalType:"string",name:"_name",type:"string"},{internalType:"string",name:"_symbol",type:"string"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"_decimals",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"_supply",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"_txFee",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"_burnFee",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"_charityFee",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"address",name:"_FeeAddress",type:"address"},{internalType:"address",name:"tokenOwner",type:"address"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"constructor"},{anonymous:!1,inputs:[{indexed:!0,internalType:"address",name:"owner",type:"address"},{indexed:!0,internalType:"address",name:"spender",type:"address"},{indexed:!1,internalType:"uint256",name:"value",type:"uint256"}],name:"Approval",type:"event"},{anonymous:!1,inputs:[{indexed:!0,internalType:"address",name:"previousOwner",type:"address"},{indexed:!0,internalType:"address",name:"newOwner",type:"address"}],name:"OwnershipTransferred",type:"event"},{anonymous:!1,inputs:[{indexed:!0,internalType:"address",name:"from",type:"address"},{indexed:!0,internalType:"address",name:"to",type:"address"},{indexed:!1,internalType:"uint256",name:"value",type:"uint256"}],name:"Transfer",type:"event"},{inputs:[],name:"FeeAddress",outputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"",type:"address"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"_BURN_FEE",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"_CHARITY_FEE",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"_TAX_FEE",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"_owner",outputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"",type:"address"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"owner",type:"address"},{internalType:"address",name:"spender",type:"address"}],name:"allowance",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"spender",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amount",type:"uint256"}],name:"approve",outputs:[{internalType:"bool",name:"",type:"bool"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"account",type:"address"}],name:"balanceOf",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"_value",type:"uint256"}],name:"burn",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"decimals",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"spender",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"subtractedValue",type:"uint256"}],name:"decreaseAllowance",outputs:[{internalType:"bool",name:"",type:"bool"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"tAmount",type:"uint256"}],name:"deliver",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"account",type:"address"}],name:"excludeAccount",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"account",type:"address"}],name:"includeAccount",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"spender",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"addedValue",type:"uint256"}],name:"increaseAllowance",outputs:[{internalType:"bool",name:"",type:"bool"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"account",type:"address"}],name:"isCharity",outputs:[{internalType:"bool",name:"",type:"bool"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"account",type:"address"}],name:"isExcluded",outputs:[{internalType:"bool",name:"",type:"bool"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"account",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amount",type:"uint256"}],name:"mint",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"name",outputs:[{internalType:"string",name:"",type:"string"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"owner",outputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"",type:"address"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"tAmount",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"bool",name:"deductTransferFee",type:"bool"}],name:"reflectionFromToken",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"renounceOwnership",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"account",type:"address"}],name:"setAsCharityAccount",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"symbol",outputs:[{internalType:"string",name:"",type:"string"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"rAmount",type:"uint256"}],name:"tokenFromReflection",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"totalBurn",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"totalCharity",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"totalFees",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[],name:"totalSupply",outputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"",type:"uint256"}],stateMutability:"view",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"recipient",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amount",type:"uint256"}],name:"transfer",outputs:[{internalType:"bool",name:"",type:"bool"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"sender",type:"address"},{internalType:"address",name:"recipient",type:"address"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"amount",type:"uint256"}],name:"transferFrom",outputs:[{internalType:"bool",name:"",type:"bool"}],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"address",name:"newOwner",type:"address"}],name:"transferOwnership",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"},{inputs:[{internalType:"uint256",name:"_txFee",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"_burnFee",type:"uint256"},{internalType:"uint256",name:"_charityFee",type:"uint256"}],name:"updateFee",outputs:[],stateMutability:"nonpayable",type:"function"}];

        // A node provider connected to the Ethereum mainnet
        const web3 = new Web3("https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org");

        const BNBTokenAddress = "0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c" //BNB
        const USDTokenAddress = "0x55d398326f99059fF775485246999027B3197955" //USDT
        let pancakeSwapContract = "0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E".toLowerCase();

        const tokenAddres = '0x55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955'; // Target Token

            async function info() 
                {
                    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(tokenAbi, tokenAddres);
                    const name = await contract.methods.name().call();
                    document.getElementById("tokenName").innerHTML = name;
                    const symbol = await contract.methods.symbol().call();
                    document.getElementById("tokenSymbol").innerHTML = symbol;
                    const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call();
                    document.getElementById("tokenDecimals").innerHTML = decimals;
                    const totalSupply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call();
                    document.getElementById("tokenSupply").innerHTML = Web3.utils.fromWei(totalSupply);
                    // document.write("<br> TotalSupply:", Web3.utils.fromWei(totalSupply));
                }

                info();

            async function calcSell(tokensToSell, tokenAddres) 
                {
                    let tokenRouter = await new web3.eth.Contract(tokenAbi, tokenAddres);
                    let tokenDecimals = await tokenRouter.methods.decimals().call();
                    tokensToSell = setDecimals(tokensToSell, tokenDecimals);
                    let amountOut;
                    try {
                    let router = await new web3.eth.Contract(pancakeSwapAbi, pancakeSwapContract);
                    amountOut = await router.methods.getAmountsOut(tokensToSell, [tokenAddres, BNBTokenAddress]).call();
                    amountOut = web3.utils.fromWei(amountOut[1]);
                    } catch (error) {}
                    if (!amountOut) return 0;
                    return amountOut;
                }

            async function calcBNBPrice() 
                {
                    let bnbToSell = web3.utils.toWei("1", "ether");
                    let amountOut;
                    try {
                    let router = await new web3.eth.Contract(pancakeSwapAbi, pancakeSwapContract);
                    amountOut = await router.methods.getAmountsOut(bnbToSell, [BNBTokenAddress, USDTokenAddress]).call();
                    amountOut = web3.utils.fromWei(amountOut[1]);
                    } catch (error) {}
                    if (!amountOut) return 0;
                    return amountOut;
                }

            function setDecimals(number, decimals) 
            {
                number = number.toString();
                let numberAbs = number.split('.')[0]
                let numberDecimals = number.split('.')[1] ? number.split('.')[1] : '';
                while (numberDecimals.length < decimals) 
                    {
                        numberDecimals += "0";
                    }
                return numberAbs + numberDecimals;
            }
            (async () => {
            let bnbPrice = await calcBNBPrice() // query pancakeswap to get the price of BNB in USDT
            document.getElementById("bnbPrice").innerHTML = bnbPrice;
            // Them amount of tokens to sell. adjust this value based on you need, you can encounter errors with high supply tokens when this value is 1.
            let tokens_to_sell = 1;
            let priceInBnb = await calcSell(tokens_to_sell, tokenAddres) / tokens_to_sell; // calculate TOKEN price in BNB
            document.getElementById("tokenPriceBNB").innerHTML = priceInBnb;
            document.getElementById("tokenPriceusd").innerHTML = priceInBnb*bnbPrice;
            })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div> Token Name : <strong id="tokenName"></strong></div>
    <div> Token Soymbol : <strong id="tokenSymbol"></strong></div>
    <div> Token Decimals : <strong id="tokenDecimals"></strong></div>
    <div> Token Supply : <strong id="tokenSupply"></strong></div>
    <div> Token Price BNB : <strong id="tokenPriceBNB"></strong></div>
    <div> Token Price USD : <strong id="tokenPriceusd"></strong></div>
    <hr>
    <p>Part-2 Need Help in this</p>
    <div> MarketCap :  <strong id="tokenCap"></strong></div>
    <div> Total BNB in Pool :  <strong id="tokenPoolBNB"></strong></div>
    <div> Total USDT in Pool :  <strong id="tokenPoolUSDT"></strong></div>



    <hr>
    <div> BNB Price : <strong id="bnbPrice"></strong></div>

    <script src="webScript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```